# How can I Query an item in the list inside the dictionary in the program?

Tags: python

```
def Program():
Storage = {}
while True:
    print('1 - Query parts\n2 - Add part\n3 - Delete part\n4 - Exit\n')
    choice = int(input())
    if choice == 1:
        while True:
            print(
                '1 - Consult All Parts\n2 - Consult Parts by Code\n3 - Consult Parts by Manufacturer\n4 - Return')
            choice2 = int(input())
            if choice2 == 1:
                for items in Storage.keys():
                    print(f'Code: {items} \n{Storage[items]}')
            elif choice2 == 2:
                search = input('Enter search: ')
                print(Storage[search])
            elif choice2 == 3:
                search = str(input('Enter the search: '))
                print(Storage[search])
            elif choice2 == 4:
                break
    elif choose == 2:
        Storage[input('Code: ')] = {'Name': input('Enter item name: '), 'brand': input('Enter item brand: '), 'value(R$) ': input('Enter the value of the item: ')}
    elif choose == 3:
        Storage.remove[input('Choose a part to remove: ')]
    elif choose == 4:
        break
```

Program()

I need to perform this part of query by manufacturer and by code, I'm relatively new with python, I've been trying several alternatives for a few days, but so far I haven't had any progress

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do this is to integrate a `list` and fill it with each `dictionary`, now when consulting you go through the list and ask for the code and manufacturer.

the code would be like this:

```
def Program():
  Storage = {}
  List = []
  while True:
      print('1 - Query parts\n2 - Add part\n3 - Delete part\n4 - Exit\n')
      choice = int(input())
      if choice == 1:
          while True:
              print(
                  '1 - Consult All Parts\n2 - Consult Parts by Code\n3 - Consult Parts by Manufacturer\n4 - Return')
              choice2 = int(input())
              if choice2 == 1:
                for item in List:
                  print(item)
              elif choice2 == 2:
                  search = input('Enter search: ')
                  for item in List:
                      if item.get("Code") == search: print(item)
              elif choice2 == 3:
                  search = input('Enter the search: ')
                  for item in List:
                      if item.get("brand") == search: print(item)
              elif choice2 == 4:
                  break
      elif choice == 2:
          Storage = {'Code': input('Code: '), 'Name': input('Enter item name: '), 'brand': input('Enter item brand: '), 'value(R$) ': input('Enter the value of the item: ')}
          List.append(Storage)
      elif choice == 3:
          for item in List:
              item.remove[input('Choose a part to remove: ')]
      elif choice == 4:
          break

Program()
```